# Laravel Cronjob Dailyat not working

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am making an online contest. Every night at 23:59 a winner should be picked using a cronjob in Laravel. When I am using everyminute it works fine. However if i change it to dailyAt('23:59') 
or cron(59 23 * * *) it doesn't
This is my commando to run te cronjob:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //          ->hourly();
    $schedule->command('pick:winner')->everyMinute(); //we should use dailyAt but this is not working;
}
```

Comment: is your cron running on 24h format?

Comment: @madalinivascu Yes!

Comment: Whats your CRON set to to run the Laravel scheduler?

Comment: @Jono20201 The Laravel Scheduler is running ervery minute
    * * * * * php /paht/to/project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: @alessandroaussems: Please check this link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939645/cron-job-minute-before-tomorrow)

Comment: Maybe you have only a time zone issue, and the Job is running but not at your local time but e.g. UTC, did you check this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently there was something wrong with the timezone, I live in Belgium. So everything excecuted 2 hours earlier. So I had to set my cronjobs differently.

```
dailyAt('21:59')//does cronjob at 23:59
```

Answer (score 8):

Try to add timezone like this:

```
$schedule->command('pick:winner')->dailyAt('23:59')->timezone('Your/Timezone');
```

Comment: This helped me - i added my timezone (Europe/Copenhagen). And it now runs like it should. Odd it does not take my app config file in count, where i have set this timezone. But works!

Comment: Hi @AndreasBaran, You can change this line in config/app.php config file like this:
`'timezone' => env('APP_TIMEZONE','UTC'),` then in your cron schedule use this helper to get timezone from app.php config file  `$timezone = config('app.timezone');`. APP_TIMEZONE has to be defined in .env file

Answer (score 3):

You should try this:

You can use custom cron schedule in `kernel.php` like:

```
$schedule->command('myTask')
         ->cron('* * * * *');
```

Hop[e this will help you

Answer (score 1):

I had faced same problem. But this Method works for me! the issue was that server time were different on cpanel server. that's why I had to use timezone to get work crojob!
You have to set every minute script on cpanel cronjob ->

```
*   *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /home/here_your_cpanel_username/public_html/your_project_folder_name/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

In your laravel projects kernel.php file ->

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    // $schedule->command('absent:cron')->daily();
$schedule->command('absent:cron')->timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
->dailyAt('23:30');
}
```